# Como retorna todos elementos do array Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, primefaces

por que tá retornando só a ultima posição do array ao invés de retorna todos ???

```
showChildModal3(Candidato: Candidato) {

this.CandidatoService.getCandidatoById(+Candidato.id)
.subscribe( data => {

  for (let c of Candidato.veiculos) {
  this.selectedObjects = []
  this.selectedObjects.push([c.id]);
  this.formularioEdit.patchValue(
    {
     nome:Candidato.nome,
     email: Candidato.email,
     cpf: Candidato.cpf,
     rua: Candidato.rua,
     bairro: Candidato.bairro,
     cidade: Candidato.cidade,
     UF: Candidato.UF,
     tipo: Candidato.tipo_cliente,
     veiculos: this.selectedObjects
    });
  }
});

 this.lgModal3.show();

      }
```

Comment: Li nos comentários que você está usando PrimeNG. No caso, quer listar os itens em uma tabela?

Comment: eu tenho um array de obejtos vindo de uma api porem quando do o for para pegar todos vem só um selecionado ao invés de vim todos que foi selecionados

Comment: Pelo que entendi do teu código, você está fazendo: 1- Recebendo um objeto `Candidato` por parâmetro. 2 - Buscando um `Candidato` pelo `Service`(sendo que já recebeu o objeto por parâmetro). 3- Está fazendo um `for` de `Candidato.veiculo` (não entendi essa parte). 4- Sempre no início do `for` tu esvazia o `selectedObjects` e insere um `id` dentro (desse jeito, sempre vai ficar apenas um `id` no array). 5- No `patchValue` você está pegando os valores que vem do objeto que está no parâmetro, e não do `data` que retorna do service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi,

supondo que seu código esteja correto (o que estou na duvida), você poderia fazer a seguinte alteração, talvez funcione:

```
showChildModal3(Candidato: Candidato) { this.CandidatoService.getCandidatoById(+Candidato.id)
.subscribe( data => {


    this.selectedObjects = []
    const valores = [];

    for (let c of Candidato.veiculos) {
      this.selectedObjects.push([c.id]);
        valores.push(
            {
                 nome:c.nome,
                 email: c.email,
                 cpf: c.cpf,
                 rua: c.rua,
                 bairro: c.bairro,
                 cidade: c.cidade,
                 UF: c.UF,
                 tipo: c.tipo_cliente,
                 veiculos: this.selectedObjects //??
            }
        )
    }

    this.formularioEdit.patchValue(valores);
});
this.lgModal3.show();}
```

No mais, você poderia alterar este for por um Array.map(fn)(https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Poderia ver mais detalhadamente sobre reactive forms:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Boa sorte.

Comment: Brigadão irmão deu certo aki !!!

Comment: @Grood não esquece de aceitar a resposta dele como correta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu estava com o mesmo problema e [isso aqui](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) funcionou pra mim.
Procura por "Select with custom trigger text" na página que tem um exemplo de como fazer segundo a documentação.

aqui meu codigo que funcionou, o ts ta muito parecido com o exemplo ai do link
`<mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Carros:</mat-label>
                <mat-select 
                   id="slt_carro"
                   [formControl]="toppings" 
                   [(ngModel)]="usuario.carros" 
                   [(value)]="usuario.carros"
                   multiple>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let carro of carros" [value]="carro.id" >{{carro.nome}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>`

Espero que isso te ajude!

Comment: vc já usou o primeng mano?

Comment: mano eu fiz exatamente como tá lá, mas não tava retornando os que estavam selecionados, então tentei de todo jeito e esse meu cód ai funcionou, pode ser q o primeiro dê certo tbm, tô estudando angular a pouco...